# cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'

Tags: python, opencv

I'm working with the following Code:

```
import cv2
tfd=cv2.CascadeClassifier(r"C:\Users\shlok\F\ml\opencv-master\data\haarcascades_cuda")
img=cv2.imread('RDJ.jpg')
gi=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
fc=tfd.detectMultiScale(gi)
print(fc)
cv2.imshow('Face detector',gi)  
cv2.waitKey()
```

However when I run it, it yields the following error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-sn_xpupm\opencv\modules\objdetect\src\cascadedetect.cpp:1689: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !empty() in function 'cv::CascadeClassifier::detectMultiScale'
```

Comment: The error indicates that your image object (`gi)` is empty.  Are you sure your image is in the directory you expect?  Have you printed `img` and `gi` to make sure they are valid?

Comment: your classifier "tfd" is initialized incorrectly. You need to pass a valid filepath

Comment: The call `cv2.imread('RDJ.jpg')` uses a relative path. That looks in the current working directory, which is very often not where novices expect. Start by providing a full path to the `.jpg` file.

Comment: if the image wasn't loaded correctly, the error would have been on the "cvtColor" line.

Comment: @TimRoberts actually no, the assertion calls `CascadeClassifier::empty()`, which checks that the xml file was loaded correctly. this assertion is not about the array argument.